# Not stop submitting when the field is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my javascript for validating the empty field

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#submit').click(function() {
                var crop = $('#crop').val();

            //Empty crop
            if (crop === "") {
                $('#cropEr2').show();
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#cropEr2').hide();

            }
        });

    });
```

the form is below

```
<form name="myForm" action="../controller/new.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table align="left" width="300" height="200">
<tbody>
<tr><td>Crop Name : </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="crop_id" value=""size="45" id="crop"     onkeyup="checkLetters(this.value);"/>
        <div id="cropEr2" style="display:none;color:red">Enter crop name</div>
        <div id="cropEr3" style="display:none;color:red">You have to enter only letters.</div>      </td></tr>
   <tr><td> <input class="button" type="reset" value="Clear Deatils" /></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_crop" />
        <input class="button" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Add Details"/></td>    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

I just want to know what's wrong with this code. its not validating !!

Comment: It seems to be working fine with the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vhzw8gL2/

Comment: @ Adrian Gunawan ,yup.It worked well before. But when i checking now its not working. any suggestions on the wrong?

Comment: `return false` should work, although the preferred way is to call `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @huz Where are you testing this?  Your code [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/bkjru04a/)

Comment: @Daedalus in my machine !! in Google chrome !!

Comment: @Huz What version, and what specific parameters?

Comment: @Daedalus version:- Version 37.0.2062.103 m of chrome and what mean the 'specific parameters' ? and this code worked properly yesterdy and even without doing anymodification now it is not. Is it a problem with my machine or what? how can i find it out?

Comment: @Huz Your code works, as demonstrated, so the only possibility is you are either entering something unknowingly, or something is being entered for you; go to the link I gave with incognito mode, and see if it works there.

Comment: @Daedalus thank you for your guide. it works in incognito mode. but not in my machine !!

Comment: @huz Then it is the fault of a plugin you have installed on your browser.

Answer (score 1):

If the user enters spaces into the field, the form will submit. Try trimming them:

```
var crop = $('#crop').val().trim();
```